# If $u(x)-\sin(x)=2\int_{0}^x \cos(x-t)u(t)dt$ then $u(x)$ equals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, integral-equations

> If $u(x)-\sin(x)=2\int_{0}^x \cos(x-t)u(t)dt$ then $u(x)$ equals
>
> $(1)\frac{e^x}{x}$
>
> $(2)\frac{x}{e^x}$
>
> $(3)xe^x$
>
> $(4)\frac{1}{xe^x}$

we have, $$u(x)-\sin(x)=2\int_{0}^x \cos(x-t)u(t)dt\tag{A}$$

Using Leibnitz's rule of differentiation under integral sign,we get
$$u'(x)-\cos(x)=2[-\int_{0}^x \sin(x-t)u(t)dt+u(x)]$$

$$\implies u'(x)-u(x)-\cos(x)=-2\int_{0}^x \sin(x-t)u(t)dt$$Using Leibnitz's rule of differentiation under integral sign,we get

$$u''(x)-u'(x)+\sin(x)=-2\int_{0}^x \cos(x-t)u(t)dt\tag{B}$$
Using equations $(A)$ and $(B)$,we get
$$u''(x)-u'(x)+\sin(x)=\sin(x)-u(x)$$

$$u''(x)-u'(x)+u(x)=0\tag{C}$$

Auxiliary equation for $(C)$ is $m^2-m+1=0\implies m=\frac{1\pm \iota\sqrt 3}{2}$

So,$u(x)=c_1\cos(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})x+c_2\sin(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})$,where $c_1,c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

**which is not in any of the option,what is wrong with my solution?**

Comment: sign mistake here $m^2+m+1=0\implies m=\frac{1\pm \iota\sqrt 3}{2}$

Comment: @user577215664: edited

Comment: You can also use $u(0)=0$ to eliminate constant.

Comment: @user577215664:please elaborate

Comment: What would the value of $u$ be at $x=0$?

Comment: Set $x=0$ here $u(x)-\sin(x)=2\int_{0}^x \cos(x-t)u(t)dt\tag{A}$  what you get ?

Comment: @user577215664:it will be $u(x)=0$

Comment: Yes $u(0)=0$ eliminate the constant in you answer and use also  the fact that the derivative of $u$ is '(0)=0$

Comment: @user577215664:we'll get $u(x)=c_2\sin(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}x)$,still it is not among the options

Comment: You made a mistake ijn your answer because you should have a exponential $e^{x/2}$ here $u(x)=c_1\cos(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})x+c_2\sin(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})$

Comment: Coefficient mistake... The characteristic equation is $m^2-2m+1=0$. I think (3).

Comment: You just need to compute $u''(0) = 2$ to differentiate between (2) & (3).

Comment: Since $u(0)=0$  the answer  1 and 4 are wrong .......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake here
$$u'(x)-\cos(x)=2\left[-\int_{0}^x \sin(x-t)u(t)dt+u(x)\right]$$
Then after this you forgot  the factor 2 this complicated the DE and the answer
$$\implies u'(x)-\color{red}{2u(x)}-\cos(x)=-2\int_{0}^x \sin(x-t)u(t)dt$$
And use this to eliminate the constants:
$$u(0)-\sin(0)=2\int_{0}^0 \cos(x-t)u(t)dt=0$$
$$ \implies u(0)=0$$
Do the same for $u'(0)$.
$$u'(0)-\color{red}{2u(0)}-\cos(0)=-2\int_{0}^0 \sin(x-t)u(t)dt$$
$$ \implies u'(0)=1$$

---

**Edit**:

Note that since $u(0)=0 $ then answer 1 and 4 are wrong.